# Bootstrap: How to reference the button that dismissed a modal on the hidden event?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

When I have a bootstrap modal, I want to capture the type of button that caused it to close.

```
<div id="fooModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel4" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel4">List</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
  ... whatever ...
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class='btn' data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true'>Action 1</button>
    <button class='btn btn-primary' aria-hidden='true'>Action 2</button>
    <button class='btn' aria-hidden='true'>Action 3</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

and in script

```
$("#fooModal")
    .modal({backdrop:'static'})
    .on('hidden', function (event) {
          console.log("foo hidden", event); // can't see the button, only the modal div itself

         // candidates for what "closed" the modal:
         // "x" button
         // "Action 1"
         // "Action 2"
         // "Action 3"

    })
    .modal('show');
```

Is there a reference to the button that caused the modal to close?

Answer (score 0):

How about handling the click event on the button instead?

```
$('#fooModal [data-dismiss="modal"]').click(function(){
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: In my case, the buttons are added to the modal itself via a handlebars template, so the number of buttons varies depending on the template used (the modal markup is re-used by multiple modal-generators, hence it being loaded using javascript). I think I might have to hook something like this, except I think I'd set an attrib on the modal div  itself so on('hidden', function(event)) can reference it through "event". Looking for something better.